# How to completely remove broken Excel addins?

Tags: macos, ms-office

I have tried to follow the official documentation to create a custom functions addin, but I have failed. How can I completely remove the broken addins?

As you can see in the screen shots I can insert two addins. But when I try to see all to hopefully find an option to remove them, they are not there.

I am using Microsoft Office Home & Business 2021 for Mac.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you go to [Office-Reset](https://office-reset.com) you can download a tool, Microsoft Office Reset, that will allow you to reset Excel back to factory fresh. If that doesn't work run the 'Completely Remove Microsoft Office' option and re-install.

The tool was written by a Microsoft engineer and is a handy dandy reset tool for all things MS Office.